# Issues plotting 3D vectors with the quiver plot and Axes3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a vector (0,0,50) that I am rotating according to some angles around a couple of axes and then want to plot all these vectors in a 3D plot.

My idea for this was to just use a quiver plot and Axes 3D.

Right now I am just trying to get it working with one vector. I am taking the rotated vector that might be, for example, (-10,30,5) and I want to always draw them from the point (0,0,0).

The Code I currently have to do this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Roted = np.array([-10,50,3]) #this will be the output of an earlier operation but it is alway in this format
VectorForPlotting = np.array([0, 0, 0, Roted[0], Roted[1], Roted[2]])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(111, projection='3d')
ax.quiver(VectorForPlotting[0], VectorForPlotting[1], VectorForPlotting[2], VectorForPlotting[3], VectorForPlotting[4], VectorForPlotting[5], pivot='tail')
plt.show()
```

Currently this just produces a blank figure box and the error:

'AttributeError: 'Quiver' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection''

From reading online it seems like for some reason it is calling quiver as if it is a 2D quiver rather than a 3D one but I cannot figure out why.

I have also tried the line

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

but get the same error.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or maybe an alternative way to do this?

When I first wrote the code I realised I was using matplotlib 1.5 something so I updated to the version 3x and still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to do `ax.subplot(111, projection='3d')` but `ax` does not have any such attribute.

You need to use the correct command for adding a 3D plot

```
fig = plt.figure() # Create a figure object
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') # Add a subplot to this figure object
```

Alternative is to use

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
```

Both gives the following figure

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry that is the syntax I had I pasted it incorrectly. I also tried the method of ax = Axes3D(fig) you just suggested and got the same error. I think I am going to have to try reinstalling some packages. Thanks for proving the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was because even though I updated matplotlib to the newest version an update will not overwrite previous parts of the library that aren't changed so if anything is broken it will stay broken.

Purging the old libraries and then completely reinstalling (in reality here I made a new virtual environment) made the code work fine.